# Jenkins with Docker cannot connect to UpdateServer

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, portainer

i tried to install jenkins with docker. But i got an error, because jenkins cannot connect to the update Server.

The Container is in the default Bridge network

This is the Error:

```
2021-06-02 05:16:53.018+0000 [id=51]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: The attempt #1 to do the action check updates server failed with an allowed exception:

java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)

    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:288)

    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)

    at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:116)

    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:218)

    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:213)

    at hudson.PluginManager.checkUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1882)

    at hudson.util.Retrier.start(Retrier.java:63)

    at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1853)

    at jenkins.DailyCheck.execute(DailyCheck.java:93)

    at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork.lambda$doRun$0(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:100)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there anyone who has an idea how can i fix this error?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Are other containers able to access the Internet?

Comment: No there is no container wich can acces to the network (only services on published ports). And there is no proxy

Comment: If the containers can not access the network how do you expect to reach the update site?

Comment: I cannot exit it. I Saw the exception in the log

Comment: Sorry i mean i cannot access it